# Как сделать вывод array php

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется два массива:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
$var = [100,200,300,400,500]
```

Как реализовать такой вывод

```
1
100
2
3
4
400
5
500
```

Спасибо, данные на входе могут быть другими не подгоняйте пожалуйста именно под этот случай

Comment: почему не нужно выводить 200, 300 после 2, 3?

Comment: Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Да именно необходим такой вывод, так как таково условие

Comment: @Mr.Nomov дак какое условие того, что не нужно выводить после 2 и 3, 200 и 300, через сколько индексов не нужно будет выводить в следующий раз, после 6 и 7?

Comment: Откуда взялись эти массивы

Comment: Условие в том, что необходим вывод этих чисел в случае ТОЛЬКО начала нового десятка. И при этом повтор этих чисел нужно избегать

Comment: домашнее задание? может, вы полностью сформулируете задачу. пока непонятно, почему 2 и 3 *начало нового десятка*, а 200 нет :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понятно, по какому принципу у вас исчезли в выводе 200 и 300 из второго массива. Если же нужно просто сортировать по "строковому" принципу:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
$var = [100,400,500];
$sum = array_merge($arr,$var);
sort($sum, SORT_STRING);
print_r($sum);
```

На выходе:

```
Array          
(              
    [0] => 1   
    [1] => 100 
    [2] => 2   
    [3] => 3   
    [4] => 4   
    [5] => 400 
    [6] => 5   
    [7] => 500 
)
```

Comment: Можно значит ещё раз есть два массива 1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3 и  11,22,33 как вывести в таком виде индексы первого массива 0 1 2  значение 2 массива 11 далее индекс 3 4 значение второго массива 22 далее индекс 5 6 7 значение 2 массива 33???

Answer (score 1):

Для того, что бы решить какую-то задачу, надо ее полностью сформулировать. Вы может и знаете ее полностью, а вот мы нет. Из текста вопроса совершенно неясно, по каким правилам выстраиваете порядок элементов из массивов.

Для решение надо просто перебрать массивы и задать условия.
К примеру, если условие великий рандом:

```
<?php
    $arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $var = [100,200,300,400,500];

    while(count($var) > 0 && count($arr) > 0){
        echo array_shift($arr) + "<br>";

        while(count($var) > 0){
            if(rand(1,3) == 2) break; //привет, я условие рандом
            echo array_shift($var) + "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Вам остается только подставить свои значения/порядок/дополнительные условия/возможно сделать еще что-то, исходя из полного текста задания.

P.S. Данный код модифицирует исходные массивы, если не хотите этого, придется завести переменные с текущим положением и проверять, не перешло ли оно границы массива.